# How to reject "invalid" documents in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

We're currently using a Couchbase Plugin (transport-couchbase) to transport and index the data into ElasticSearch (http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-elastic-search/)

I've taken a look at ElasticSearch's mapping documentation here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

My understanding is that if you rely on defaults for ElasticSearch, once a document gets indexed, ElasticSearch will create a dynamic mapping for that document type. This is what we've defaulted to.

We ran into issues where **after** adding a specific document type, and when the transport plugin inserts an "invalid" document (the document's field type is now different -- from string -> array), ElasticSearch throws an exception and essentially breaks the replication from Couchbase to ElasticSearch. The exception looks like this:

```
 Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: unknown property 
 [xyz]
 java.lang.RuntimeException: indexing error MapperParsingException[failed to parse
 [doc.myfield]]; nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property[xyz]]
```

Is there a way we can configure ElasticSearch so that "invalid" documents simply get filtered without throwing exception and breaking the replication?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you not define the mapping of your documents as you want them to be, set `index.mapper.dynamic: false` in your `elasticsearch.yml` file, and in theory (untested) elasticsearch (in my mind) should reject the invalid documents. Just a thought.

Comment: @NathanSmith The mapping is too weak to allow proper checking of documents. Basically it only allows field names and primitive types. No vocabularies, ranges, look-ups, etc. Maybe if one could define custom types it would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties" : {
            "message" : {"type" : "string", "store" : true }
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html